# Compare parsed JSON from pre-populated SQLite DB and update if not similar

Tags: android, json, sqlite, parsing

I've been stuck at this problem for a while on `Android`.

Is it possible to compare an `SQLite` local database from the parsed `JSON` objects and update the table if it's not similar?

For example, I have a pre-populated `SQLite` database, and someone updates the server database. So instead of deleting the previous database and repopulating the app's local `SQLite` database, it'll just do a background `JSON` parsing and compare the contents of the `SQLite` database.

If it finds a row that's changed, it'll just pull that `JSON` object and update its counterpart on the local `SQLite` database.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how expensive it is to check every row of your server db on a background process but here's a suggestion. Why don't you create a somewhat notifications table from the server and then any relevant change in the server db that concerns your local sqlite db must be published in this table. Your background process would now just be to check the notifications table and create code that will update your local db accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

if the table schema  contains a timestamp column thats reflects time of insert or update,
you can download a list of rows with the timestamp and compare to your local database prior then just download and replace the complete row on those records with older timestamps in the local database.

you'll need to take into account records that have been deleted on the server.